# Caching readdir()

Tags: php, caching

Is there anyway to cache readdir() result? Right now I do readdir() on a directory tree everytime I enter a specific webpage on the website.

**UPDATE:**

- The directory structure is the same for all users.
- Unfortunately my shared host do not support APC or memcache :-(

Comment: See Updated code for a simple file system version ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Memcache` with `filemtime`

```
$path = __DIR__ . "/test";
$cache = new Memcache();
$cache->addserver("localhost");

$key = sha1($path);
$info = $cache->get(sha1($path));

if ($info && $info->time == filemtime($path)) {
    echo "Cache Copy ", date("Y-m-d g:i:s", $info->time);
} else {
    $info = new stdClass();
    $info->readDir = array_map("strval", iterator_to_array(new FilesystemIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)));
    $info->time = filemtime($path);
    $cache->set($key, $info, MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 0);
    echo "Path Changed ", date("Y-m-d g:i:s", $info->time);
}

var_dump(array_values($info->readDir));
```

**Update**

> Unfortunately my shared host do not support APC or memcache :-(

You can use File Systems

```
$path = __DIR__ . "/test";
$cache = new MyCache(__DIR__ . "/a");

$key = sha1($path);
$info = $cache->get($key);

if ($info && $info->time == filemtime($path)) {
    echo "Cache Copy ", date("Y-m-d g:i:s", $info->time);
} else {
    $info = new stdClass();
    $info->readDir = array_map("strval", iterator_to_array(new FilesystemIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)));
    $info->time = filemtime($path);
    $cache->set($key, $info, MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 0);
    echo "Path Changed ", date("Y-m-d g:i:s", $info->time);
}

var_dump(array_values((array) $info->readDir));
```

Class Used

```
class MyCache {
    private $path;

    function __construct($path) {
        is_writable($path) or trigger_error("Path Not Writeable");
        is_dir($path) or trigger_error("Path Not a Directory");
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    function get($key) {
        $file = $this->path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $key . ".cache";
        if (! is_file($file))
            return false;
        $data = file_get_contents($file);
        substr($data, 0, 2) == "##" and $data = gzinflate(substr($data, 2));
        return json_decode($data);
    }

    function set($key, $value, $compression = 0) {
        $data = json_encode($value);
        $compression and $data = gzdeflate($data, 9) and $data = "##" . $data;
        return file_put_contents($this->path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $key . ".cache", $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in a session variable if you start a session. Look at the session_start() function, etc.

Comment: this would store the same data for every user on the site, and may involve starting sessions unnecessarily. The dir structure could be cached application-wide, unless for some reason not mentioned in the question the directory is specific to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache any serializable PHP structure using a number of methods. PHP ships with APC these days, so I suggest looking at APC object caching.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.apc.php

Be sure to have some logic for clearing the cache when the directory structure changes.