# PHP get more then one argument in command line

Tags: php, command-line

On php command line i can read only the first argument. When i add the site name the program not breaking before the password input.

```
echo "Site name: ";
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$base_name = trim(fgets($handle));
fclose($handle);

echo "Password:";
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$base_password = trim(fgets($handle));
fclose($handle);
```

How can i read these two variables from stdin?

Comment: BTW, from the command line `$base_name = trim(fgets(STDIN));` works here on it's own rather then opening/closing handles yourself.

Comment: Thanks for help! This is working!:
`echo "Site name: ";
$base_name = trim(fgets(STDIN));
echo "Password: ";
$base_password = trim(fgets(STDIN));

echo "\n\n\n Site name: $base_name \n\n Password: $base_password";
`

Comment: You should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622677/caching-readdir/13623277#13623277 ... example with directory

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments passed at command time will be in the global `$argv` as well as the super global `$_SERVER["argv"]` with `$argv[0]` and `$_SERVER["argv"][0]` being the command that was called.

A useful function for parsing out for example the call `./myscript.php --user=root --password=foobar`

```
function parse_argvs(){
    if( $params = $_SERVER["argv"] ){
        $file = array_shift( $params );
        while( $params ){
            $param = array_shift( $params );
            switch( strspn( $param, "-" ) ){
                case( 1 ):
                    $OPTS[ trim( $param, " -" ) ] = array_shift( $params );
                break;
                case( 2 ):
                    list( $key, $value ) = explode( "=", $param );
                    $OPTS[ trim( $key, " -" ) ] = $value;
                break;
                default:
                    $OPTS[ $param ] = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $OPTS ?: array();
}
```

Called something like

```
$parsed = parse_argvs();
echo $parsed['user']; //root
echo $parsed['password']; //password
```

These are *actual* command line arguments passed at call time. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$base_name     = readline("Site Name: ");
$base_password = readline("Password: ");
```

[PHP Readline Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php)

Comment: To my understanding the readline extension is not installed by default.

Comment: Maybe work i can't test, no "readline" function in default php install on redhat.